# CSS selector for descendents till a certain tag is encountered

Tags: css

I am wondering if there is a CSS selector that can be used to select all descendants until a certain tag is encountered.

So for instance, in the DOM structure below, I would like to add a selector to "id1", so that it can style all descendants upto but not including "id4". In other words, the div corresponding to class1 and class2. I am aware of id1 and id4 beforehand, but I am not aware of class1 and class2 (there could be many more in the chain till I hit "id4"). I would like the style to be applied to the div corresponding to class1 and class2, but nothing else. Basically the application divs already have their position set to something, and I want to be able to keep that as it is, just modify the position for the div corresponding to class1 and class2.

I would ideally like to avoid having to list all the divs that I am using since the application has a rather large number of divs under the id "deep-nesting-of-known-divs-here"

```
<div id="id 1">
   <div class="class1">
       <div class="class2">
           <div id="id4">
               <div id="deep-nesting-of-known-divs-here">
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The reason is that I have run into a strange problem on Safari for a certain site. I have an extension that is injecting an iframe into page. After injecting the iframe, the page seems to be running a script that causes the id2 and id3 to be injected between id1 and id4. As a result, the iframe does not display properly.

Comment: *Most* styles applied to `id4`'s ancestors will be inherited by `id4`.  You'd have to override each inherited style individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, IDs aren't the best example, because due to their nature, they would be unique and predictable - precisely not what you're describing in your example.

But anyway, here's how you do it - you don't get an "until" selector in css, but you can check child elements. That means you could either style every element that isn't #id4 or a child of it, or style every element, then reset your styles for every element that's #id4 or a child of it:

```
/* style every div element that's not #id4 or a child of it */

#id1 :not(#id4) div:not(#id4) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

```
/* style every div, then reset divs that are #id4 or a child of it */

#id1 div {
  background-color: red;
}

#id1 #id4, #id1 #id4 div {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I think I was looking for (1) above (/* style every div element that's not #id4 or a child of it */). Could you possibly tell me how it is preventing the selection of all descendants of #id4?

Comment: @AshD: It selects all divs without the id "id4", within a div that doesn't have the id "id4", within the div with id "id1".  The center part is the key element, as it prevents all children of #id4 of ever getting selected.

Comment: Thank you. I do not have the reputation to add + votes otherwise I would have. Thank you very much again. I need to learn CSS!

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely have to set a style for all descendants and then reset for `#id4`.

Try something like:

```css
#id1 div {
    color: red;
}
#id1 #id4 {
    color: black;
}
```

You could also get a bit more specific for your descendant selector use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and then reset for target element:

```css
#id1 [id^="id"] {
    color: red;
}
#id1 #id4 {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure if this is a practical solution for me given that there are many divs inside id4

Comment: It's practical if you don't know the number of elements that you need to target between #id1 and #id4.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to use css psuedo selectors. [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp). One way to solve it would be to give all of the classes the class name of `id` then do `.id:not(:last-child)`. There is probably a better way to solve it but this would be my approach :-)